# Phonegap 2.5.0: Error during project creation

Tags: android, cordova

I'm trying to follow the [Getting Started with Android](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html) tutorial on Windows. I'm on step 4. Setup a New Project. I type in `./create c:\projects\test com.example.test test`, then receive an error:

```
An unexpected error occurred: ANDROID_BIN="${ANDROID_BIN:=$( which android )}" exited with 1
Deleting project...
```

I've modified my `PATH` system environment variable, adding `%ANDROID_HOME%\tools` and `%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools`. `%ANDROID_HOME%` points to `c:\adt-bundle\sdk`.

I can run the following commands successfully:

- `java`
- `javac`
- `ant`
- `adb`

However, running `android` results in `-bash: android: command not found`.

I'm stumped. Anyone know what I'm missing in order to be able to create Phonegap projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure you can run the commands below from your terminal:

```
ant -version
java -version
android -h
```

If you get command not found, you need to fix that first before trying to create Phonegap projects. Once you update your PATH variable, you need to restart the command prompt/terminal before be able to use those commands.

To make things easier, make sure you have ANT_HOME, JAVA_HOME and ANDROID_HOME variable defined too!

Edit:
Make sure you are using Window's command prompt and not cygwin shell.

Comment: `ant -version` and `java -version` work great. However, I still get `command not found` for `android -h`. Variables for `ANT_HOME` and `JAVA_HOME` have already been defined as well.

Comment: Try to add the path to tools and platform-tools in your user variable's PATH and not on the system variables's PATH. Some people report success with it.

Comment: Adding the `PATH` user variable didn't fix the problem either unfortunately. `android: command not found`

Comment: Try to go to the %ANDROID_HOME%\tools and run android -h. Do you able to do that? If so, this is a PATH problem.

Comment: Running `./android.bat -h` from within the `%ANDROID_HOME%\tools` directory works. Running it without `.bat` fails.

Comment: Looks like you have to double-triple check your PATH configuration. Just to be clear for all of us, you use window's command prompt right? not cygwin shell or something similar.

Comment: That's what it was! I was using Cygwin... I was able to successfully create a Phonegap project from the Windows command prompt.